# question about $p$-Sylow subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I was wondering whether it is necessarily true that if $P_1$ and $P_2$ are Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ then $P_2\subseteq N_G(P_1)$. I don't think it is because since they're both Sylow $p$-groups, they can't be normal. I think that $P_2$ would not be in $N_G(P_1)$ then. Some help? Thanks!

Comment: How many Sylow $p$-subgroups can $N_G(P_1)$ have?

Comment: @JackSchmidt Well, it definitely has $P_1$, but that's all I can think of.

Comment: @Sarah do you mean "then $P_2\not\subset N_G(P_1)$" in your first sentence?

Comment: @JérémyBlanc No, I meant what I wrote, but I think what you have written is true. I just can't see why.

Comment: @Sarah If you really meant this, then the answer is trivially no. Take for example the symmetric group on $3$ letters. The other question is more interesting (and has an answer below).

Comment: So $N_G(P_1)$ has a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup. Does that help you answer Jack Schmidt's question?

Comment: Nearly a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794382/if-q-and-p-are-distinct-p-sylow-subgroups-then-q-not-subseteq-n-gp

Answer (score 1):

There's the following general fact about $p$-groups and $p$-sylow groups.

> If $G$ is a group, $H \leq G$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup, for some prime $p$, then for every $K \leq G$a $p$-subgroup such that $K \leq N_G(H)$ then $K \leq H$.

**Exercise**: prove it. :)